# Can I use restrict qualifier in this function?

Tags: c, c99, undefined-behavior, c11, restrict-qualifier

I read the standard but still cannot be sure:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void repl(char *restrict ap){
    char *cp=strchr(ap,(int)'m');
    *cp='M';
}

int main(){
    char arr[] = "example";
    repl(arr);
    puts(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

In the function `repl`, I used `strchr` to get another pointer for modifying the object. I expect the result is the string with the first `m` replaced with `M`.

But could this be undefined behavior?

If yes, then what about using `ap[cp-ap]='M';` instead of `*cp='M';`?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't indicate anything very much in this context. AFAICT, you need two pointer variables in an argument list for it to make a difference.  I see nothing that would break the restrict in the code you show.

Comment: Literals such as `'m'` already have type `int`. So no need to cast them, and in any case, even if the types were different a cast is not a good idea, anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

Aliasing rules allow to access any variable through its own type or by the character type (including its signed / unsigned variant). It means that `*cp='M';` is specified behavior without any special precaution needed as `*cp` is of character type.

On a different subject you don't need to cast `'m'` in `(int)'m'` as `'m'` is already of type `int` in C.

Comment: You are right, I just realized the literal is of type `int`. Thanks. Actually I asked the question because I worried about that maybe complier doesn't know the relation between `cp` and `ap` and simply believes that `"example"` is never modifed.

Comment: @ouah Are you saying that  a char/unsigned char pointer is allowed to alias a restrict pointer ? (If so, what's the point of restrict on the arguments of strcpy() ?)

Comment: @nos `restrict` is used in `strcpy` as a hint (for optimization purposes) to inform the compiler that the two pointers don't alias . C allows a `char *` to alias any other pointer.

Comment: @ouah 6.7.3-7 of c99 seems to say it's more than a hint... though I'm not able to decipher the actual definition in 6.7.3.1

Answer (score 0):

It's not undefined behaviour, because the pointer cp is derived from the pointer variable ap.

How does the compiler know that cp is derived from ap? It doesn't have to know. First, whether the compiler knows or not doesn't change that the behaviour is defined or undefined. The rule isn't "if the compiler knows...", the rule is "if cp is derived from ap".

As long as the compiler cannot prove that cp wasn't derived from ap, it must provide the exact same semantics as if you hadn't used the restrict keyword.

Comment: Can I be a little curious about how the compiler knows `cp` is derived from `ap` (rather than irrelevant source)?  :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the impression that you get the purpose of the `restrict` modifier wrong. It is a guarantee that the caller of the function has to provide, namely that the object isn't accessible through any other pointer and wouldn't be modified unexpectedly by using such another pointer. So the *usage* of `restrict` qualified pointers doesn't lead to UB.

In addition in your case you are passing such a pointer to a function. After that the compiler can't assume anymore that the pointer doesn't alias, e.g to a global variable or to the pointer that the function returns. (which it actually does)

To give you an example, it is not the function `memcpy` which has UB. But it would be your call to memcpy that hasn't defined behavior if the two pointers point to overlapping objects.